# Why are Heisenberg's uncertaity principle and the quantum theory considered to upset or to affect human experience of reality?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, causation, quantum-physics

These two principles seem to have caused an uproar within the scientific community and to have supposedly disrupted notions of 'causality'. Since both features already existed before their 'discovery' and operate at such a miniscule level, how can they alter what we experience in our reality of everyday life.
Black holes exert millions and even billions of more power than our sun and each galaxy is said to have one. And yet they exert no discernable effect on life on earth. It seems that those who make claims about this overthrow of Newton's theories and who postulate some worldview changing effect from these phenomena are just confused, could that be possible?

Comment: I do not follow the reasoning. Black holes can exist even under Newton's theory, and the gravity falls as a square of a distance. That's why the effect on us is miniscule, but it is well detectable with telescopes, not postulated. For that matter, how does the effect on our everyday lives matter at all in the grand scheme of things? We are not the pinnacle of creation, and people had everyday lives long before Newton, thinking that the Earth is flat or stands still at the center of revolving crystal spheres.

Comment: See [Quantum mechanical paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_paradox#Quantum_mechanical_paradoxes): "A significant set of physical paradoxes are associated with the privileged position of the observer in quantum mechanics." Those are the puzzling aspects of QM (nothing to do with Black Holes).

Comment: Quantum mechanics affects macro-world too. Perhaps, without uncertainty principle the way neurons operate would be different and that's a huge effect on everyday life and experiences. But it is only a possibility.

Comment: The main philosophical issue with quantum physics is that it makes it harder to imagine a self-contained universe where universal laws explain the behavior of all systems including measuring devices & human measurers. There are ways to recover an objective world but they involve new strange assumptions like instantaneous causality in Bohm's interp. (see p. 46-47 of [this paper by John Bell](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00220688/document) on how Einstein's main objection to QM was the lack of an objective world with local causality) or the multiverse of the many-worlds interp.

Comment: See his “Physics and Philosophy”. He basically tells non-physicists to forget about QM. There was a 2007 reprint of this book I believe.

Comment: Heisenberg had a very good education. He understood philosophy very well. In many ways I think he would have disagreed with Hawking’s comments about philosophy.

Comment: @Gordon- My question is why should something operating at the atomic level of activity be considered to have some sort of controlling capacity over how ;reality is defined, it's absurd.

Comment: @conifold- virtually everything 'viewed' through a telescope in deep space is pure conjecture made about a wisp of light leftover from objects which ceased to exist billions of years ago. Images 'created' from these captures of light are all artificially produced from conjecture about what these long dead objects might have looked like IF there was the possibility (which there is not) of somehow 'viewing them with the human eye. Both 'uncertainty and quantum objects are also artificial depictions from the perspective of some so called 'observer'. Again, is that 'Science' or 'fiction'?

Comment: "My question is why should something operating at the atomic level of activity be considered to have some sort of controlling capacity over how ;reality is defined" Because most physicists are [reductionists](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/11/03/physicalist-anti-reductionism/), not necessarily in any metaphysical sense but just in the sense that they believe the measurable behavior of complex systems is always derivable in principle from the simplest parts making them up and the fundamental laws governing those parts.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is yes -- too many (most?) people are quite confused.

Specifically, they are confused about things that we don't *experience* on a day-to-day basis. Things that can only be understood through mental models and abstract reasoning.

Remarkably, one the first concepts they would struggle with, is also fundamental to our notion of *truth*, to our ability to tell whether something *is* true, and to our capacity for the knowledge itself.

Specifically, it's the objective nature reality that they are not comfortable with. Yet that is exactly what we must assume -- the objective and explainable reality that we all share and are a part of -- before we can know of anything else. Truth and knowledge, therefore, must be, by definition, *objective*.

Yet when a person relies exclusively on their *own* experience, when their *own* experience is everything they will ever know, it makes the necessarily *subjective*.

BTW, as extreme as it sounds, it is a very old news indeed:
**‟***And although the **lógos** is common, most people live as if they had their own private understanding.*
   -- Heraclitus, circa 450 BC

And that's the reason for their fascination with Quantum Mechanics -- because,  on the surface, it undermines the concept of objective reality, if only on the subatomic scale.

Comment: How can there exist any objective knowledge for humans to grasp if their experience of the sensible world is only subjective?

Comment: "How can there exist any objective?" -- well, what is your definition of an "objective"? or you wanted *me* to explain what it is, but didn't how to ask? ;)

Comment: It has become more or less common knowledge that the concept of 'objective' knowledge involves a built-in contradiction. Since human perception of the sensible world does not include any direct, concrete access to knowledge and because the researcher who proposes the hypothesis, sets up the experiment, captures and measures the results and finally ANALYZES and reports on the results, apparently miraculously the human who has no direct access to the sensible world has become the 'agent' who declares the experiment's results as objective knowledge. The science is OK. What is  said  is not.